# all js files in javascript/packs are not loading in my application in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, stimulusjs

The application was working fine. Its a Rails 5.1 with StimulusJS.

I've tried to do in the server

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

with no effect.

it seems like it isn't accesible

this is the relevant code in **production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Analytics account
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
```

and a screen of the console showing the error

[image: browser console log]

Answer (score 0):

Given the assets in the "normal" pipeline were working, and after trying variations in syntax what finally worked was getting by ssh in the server, and running this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

It seems normal assets and webpacker go two different ways.